# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'data[sub_props[i]]')

Tags: android, react-native

I am building a react native app and have got this error. I checked the logs and found that data[sub_props[i]] is causing the issue in :

```
"var": function _var(a, b) {
  var not_found = b === undefined ? null : b;
  var sub_props = String(a).split(".");
  var data = this;
  for (var i = 0; i < sub_props.length; i++) {
    data = data[sub_props[i]];
    if (data === undefined) {
      return not_found;
    }
  }
  return data;
},
```

I am not able to understand what is it that is causing this error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks. I am building it on android platform.

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.46.4

Answer (score 0):

This line basically destroys the `data` array and assigns it to a single value (probably `null`) and future iterations try to iterate on a non-iterable or `null` object.

```
data = data[sub_props[i]];
```

Better create a new variable to assign `data[sub_props[i]]` like `temp`:

```
var data = this;
var temp;
for (var i = 0; i < sub_props.length; i++) {
   temp= data[sub_props[i]];
   if (temp=== undefined) {
      return not_found;
   }
 }
 return temp;
```